# Target option that contains *** and remove option using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I must be overlooking something. I want to target an option by its text. Once it's targeted, I want to remove the entire option.

HTML:

```
<select id="test">
<option value="x">Apple</option>
<option value="xx">Banana</option>
<option value="xxz">Carrot</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
if ($('#test option').contains('App')) {
     $(this).remove();
}
```

So:

1. Target Option that contains "App"
2. Remove Option that contains "App"

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/HAvQz/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/HAvQz/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `this` in your code (well, you have one, it's `window`).

Simply do this :

```
$('#test option:contains("Apple")').remove();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rFSM3/)